# How to add legend inside Python's Bokeh circle plot

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have the following code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers

colormap = {'setosa': 'red', 'versicolor': 'green', 'virginica': 'blue'}
colors = [colormap[x] for x in flowers['species']]

p = figure(title = "Iris Morphology")
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Length'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Width'

p.circle(flowers["petal_length"], flowers["petal_width"],
         color=colors, fill_alpha=0.2, size=10)

output_file("iris.html", title="iris.py example")

show(p)
```

Which produces this plot

[image]

How can I add legend based on the color of the circle to the plot?
Where:

- setosa     : red
- versicolor : green
- virginica  : blue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way that comes to mind is to define a ColumnDataSource to your plot to which you pass your data and from there reference the column with the `"species"` data from your dataframe.

Here is your code rework using this solution:

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers

from bokeh.plotting import (ColumnDataSource, figure, show, output_file)
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers

colormap = {'setosa': 'red', 'versicolor': 'green', 'virginica': 'blue'}
colors = [colormap[x] for x in flowers['species']]
flowers['colors'] = colors

source = ColumnDataSource(flowers)

p = figure(title = "Iris Morphology")
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Length'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Width'

p.circle("petal_length", "petal_width",
         color='colors', fill_alpha=0.2, size=10, legend='species',source=source)
p.legend.location = "top_left"

output_file("iris.html", title="iris.py example")

show(p)
```

And this is what you should obtain. I additionally put the legend to the right so it is not inserted on top of the plot:

[image: Plot with solution]

Answer (score 1):

You can use for-loop to plot it:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers

colormap = {'setosa': 'red', 'versicolor': 'green', 'virginica': 'blue'}
colors = [colormap[x] for x in flowers['species']]


p = figure(title = "Iris Morphology")
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Length'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Width'


for specie in colormap.keys():
    df = flowers[flowers['species']==specie]
    p.circle(df["petal_length"], df["petal_width"],
             color=colormap[specie], fill_alpha=0.2, size=10, legend=specie)

p.legend.location = "top_left"


output_file("iris.html", title="iris.py example")

show(p)
```

[image]